# How to add dynamic column with date column in access database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

How to add dynamic column with date column. In first column i have date and in second column i have Integer value. like: Column A has date value and column b is having numbers,  Expecting output in date with increase of date.

Example: Column A :- 10/20/2017 , Column B is 5. Output Should be 10/25/2017.

Comment: Neither of your tags are appropriate; the hovertext on one even explicitly tells you not to use it for exactly what you've used it for.

Comment: I have edited my question in a proper way.

Comment: not an expert in access but check if column A field is date field (if not cast it to date field) & apply dateadd function with the respective day interval as column B. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_dateadd.asp

Comment: Show the expression you attempted. This is a simple calculation. Since day is default unit when doing arithmetic with Date value, don't even need DateAdd function. `[ColumnA] + [ColumnB]`, assuming ColumnA is a DateTime type.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic date field for MS Access, this works on Access 2007, 2010.

Here is how:

- Date1 of type Date/Time
- NbrDays of type Number
- Date2 of type Calculated

  - Expression: IIf((IsNull([date1]) Or IsNull([NbrDays])),Null,[date1]+[NbrDays])
  - Result Type: Date/Time.

This expression handles null values as well, see illustration.

[image: Dynamic date field/column on Access]

Comment: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: Originally yes, yet nowadays DBMS tables support the feature of calculated fields (MS Access) or generated columns (MySql).
 References:
**Add a calculated field to a table**
[link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3) **CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns**
[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Whether it's a feature or not is irrelevant. What is relevant is that it's a bad idea.